# Insert Select Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following problem.

I tried to do this:

```
DB::table('crm_client_type')
  ->insertSelect(
    DB::connection('connection2')
      ->table('view_tipo_cliente')
      ->select('id_prospecto', 'id', 'plan', 'tipo_cliente')
  );
```

however, it told me that:

> insertSelect is available in QueryBuilder

What I need is to do an insert select somehow knowing that one of the tables is located in another connection (server) and I can't do blocks like FOR or FOREACH because the server hangs

```
DB::table('crm_tipo_cliente')
  ->insertSelect(
    DB::connection('connection2')
      ->table('view_tipo_cliente')
      ->select('id_prospecto', 'cedula', 'plan', 'tipo_cliente')
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

The insertSelect method is not available in Laravel's QueryBuilder by default. Try it

```
DB::connection('connection2')
    ->table('view_tipo_cliente')
    ->select('id_prospecto', 'cedula', 'plan', 'tipo_cliente')
    ->each(function ($row) {
        DB::table('crm_tipo_cliente')->insert([
            'id_prospecto' => $row->id_prospecto,
            'cedula' => $row->cedula,
            'plan' => $row->plan,
            'tipo_cliente' => $row->tipo_cliente,
        ]);
    });
```

Comment: try DB::connection('connection2')
    ->table('view_type_customer')
    ->select('id_prospecto', 'id', 'plan', 'tipo_cliente')
    ->each(function ($row) {
        DB::table('crm_client_type')->insert([
            'id_prospect' => $row->id_prospect,
            'certificate' => $row->certificate,
            'plan' => $row->plan,
            'customer_type' => $row->customer_type,
        ]);
    });


but it gave me this error
You must specify an orderBy clause when using this function.


vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php:2291

Comment: add ->orderBy('some_column')  after - select()